# magento session destroy after redirect from payment method

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, checkoutsession

We are integrating 3rd party payment method.
When returning from payment channel to return url, the session destroyed.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advanced

Comment: Do you want to reserve the cart session?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
$quote = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory')->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());
 
$quote->setReservedOrderId(null);
$quote->setIsActive(true);
$quote->removePayment();
$quote->save();
$this->checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
$this->cart->setQuote($quote);
$this->checkoutSession->restoreQuote();
```

**NOTE**: do not use Object manager, but you need to use the magento standard to implement this code on the place where you want this one.

Answer (score 0):

Where  we will put this code
Please can you explain  ???

Comment: Where we will put this code Please can you explain ???

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/195544)

Answer (score 0):

There is a samesite patch from Adobe Commerce (Magento) which is used to fix this issue.